# Merge/overlap multiple audio tracks into one file using python (all of them should play at the same time)

Tags: python, audio-player

I have a list of audio files.
Example:

```
["drums.wav","guitar.wav","piano.wav",....]
```

How to merge/overlap the files so they play together using Python? I have tried using `pydub` along with a for loop to iterate over the list but it takes very long and the final track does not have all the instruments. What should I do?